# Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string after WP 4.7

Tags: php, functions, theme-development

This one has me baffled because the code has worked for the past 2 years but after the most recent WordPress update to 4.7 it thru a fit.

WordPress is throwing the error Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in  on line 42 of functions.php which happens to be this line:

```
WHERE {$wpdb->terms}.term_id = {$term_id}
```

in the chunk of code below. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
// Detects Category ID for category Info custom post type
function wph_wp() {
global $wpdb, $cc_post_id;

$terms = null;
$cc_post_id = null;

if (is_category()) {
    $term = get_queried_object();
    $terms = array($term->term_id);
} elseif (is_single()) {
    $post = get_queried_object();
    $terms = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);
}

if (!empty($terms)) {
    foreach ($terms as $term_id) {
        $cc_post_id = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("
            SELECT {$wpdb->posts}.ID FROM {$wpdb->terms} 
            JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} ON {$wpdb->terms}.term_id = {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy = 'category'
            JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_taxonomy_id = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id
            JOIN {$wpdb->posts} ON {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id = {$wpdb->posts}.ID AND post_type = 'category_info'
            WHERE {$wpdb->terms}.term_id = {$term_id}
        ", ""));
        if (!empty($cc_post_id)) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there was a change in 4.7, but `wp_get_post_categories` returns an array of category *objects*, not IDs, so when you loop over the `$terms`, `$term_id` is actually an object.

Add the argument `'fields' => 'ids'` to the `wp_get_post_categories`-call and you should be good to go – [it'll return an array of category IDs instead](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_categories/#return).

```
$terms = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID, ['fields' => 'ids']);
```

Comment: Strangely the issue corrected itself but you had a good call out in something I should be doing differently. Thank you.